Cancelling terms in charge-balance equation
Particularly, I faced this issue while applying charge balance concept in solubility-equilibirum problem. For more clarity, I would like to give the original question (I donot know the source, please let me know)

Biochemical reactions take place in buffered aqueous environments. For example, the $\mathrm{p}$H of the blood is maintained around $7.4$ by the buffering action of carbonate, phosphate, and proteins. Many chemical reactions in the laboratory are also carried out in buffer solutions. In this problem, let’s consider the solubility equilibrium in a buffer solution.
$12.1)$ $\ce{H2S}$ gas with a volume of $\pu{440 cm^{3}}$ at STP can be dissolved in $\pu{100 cm^{3}}$ of water at $\pu{25°C}$. Calculate the concentration of $\ce{H2S}\pu{(mol dm^{–3})}$ in water saturated with $\ce{H2S}$. Assume that there is no volume change in water upon dissolution of $\ce{H2S}$. 
$12.2)$ Assume that equilibrium is established after a $\ce{FeCl2}$ solution with a concentration of $\pu{1.0×10^{–2} mol dm^{–3}}$ is saturated with $\ce{H2S}$ by continuously bubbling of $\ce{H2S}$ into the solution. 
$K_\mathrm{sp}\ce{(FeS)} = \ce{[Fe^2+][S^2–]} = 8.0×10^{–19}$ at $\pu{25°C}$ 
For acid dissociation of $\ce{H2S}$, $K_\mathrm{1} = \frac{\ce{[H+][HS-]}}{\ce{[H2S]}} = 9.5×10^{-8} $  $K_\mathrm{2} = \frac{\ce{[H+][S^2-]}}{\ce{[HS-]}} = 1.3×10^{-14} $
For autoprotolysis of water: $K_\mathrm{w} = \ce{[H+][OH-]} = 10^{-14}$
In the solution, the positive charge is balanced by the negative charge:
$$\ce{[H+] + 2[Fe^2+] = [Cl–] + [OH–] + [HS–] + 2[S^2–]}$$
Cross out terms that are negligibly small in the charge balance equation, in order to
determine $\ce{[H+]}$ and $\ce{[Fe^2+]}$. Would you increase or decrease the pH of the solution to precipitate more $\ce{FeS}$? How does the increase of $\mathrm{p}$H by $1$ affect the concentration of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ ion?


I found the answer to the first question as $\pu{0.18 M}$
For the second question, it is very obvious that we must increase the $\mathrm{p}$H so that no common ion effect is applied and that we get a higher ionic product. The problem I faced was to deduce the same, using the charge balance equation. I want to share my approach, so that I could know if this is the right way to do so

significant edits were undertaken as per the prior discussion in the comments and the answer to this post


We know that $\ce{[Cl-]}$ has a constant value of $2\times10^{-2}$ and is much higher than the rest of the constants, so throughout the equation I shall be using this. Also consider the following expressions:
$\ce{[OH-]} = \frac{K_\mathrm{w}}{\ce{[H+]}}$ ; $\ce{[HS-]} = \frac{K_\mathrm{1}\times \ce{[H2S]}}{\ce{[H+]}} = \frac{K_\mathrm{1}\times 0.18}{\ce{[H+]}}$ ; $\ce{[S^2-]} = \frac{K_\mathrm{sp}}{\ce{[Fe^2+]}}$
Substituing these values in the charge balance equation, we get:
$$\ce{[H+] + 2[Fe^2+]} = 2\times10^{-2} + \frac{K_\mathrm{w}}{\ce{[H+]}} + \frac{K_\mathrm{1}\times 0.18}{\ce{[H+]}} + 2\times\frac{K_\mathrm{sp}}{\ce{[Fe^2+]}}$$

Considering $\frac{K_\mathrm{w}}{\ce{[H+]}}, \frac{K_\mathrm{1}\times 0.18}{\ce{[H+]}}$ and $2\times\frac{K_\mathrm{sp}}{\ce{[Fe^2+]}}$ to be negligible

I am left with a rather neat equation:
$$\ce{2[Fe+] + [H+] = 2\times10^{-2}}$$

Upon evaluating this result, in order to increase precipitation, I will have to decrease $\ce{[H+]}$ or increase $\mathrm{p}$H, on sync with our prior conclusion.


Consider the following evaluations:
$$\ce{H2S <=> 2H+ + S^2-}$$ 
Where $K_{net} = K_\mathrm{1}\times K_\mathrm{2} = 1.235\times10^{-21}$
$$\ce{[S^2-] =} \frac{K_{net}\times\ce{[H2S]}}{\ce{[H+]^2}} = \frac{K_{net}\times0.18}{\ce{[H+]^2}}$$
Also,
$$\ce{[Fe^2+] =} \frac{K_\mathrm{sp}}{\ce{[S^2-]}} = \frac{K_\mathrm{sp}}{\frac{K_{net}\times0.18}{\ce{[H+]^2}}} = \frac{\ce{[H+]^2}}{2.77\times10^{-4}}$$
plugging this expression in the final charge-balance equation,
$$\frac{\ce{[H+]^2}}{2.77\times10^{-4}} + \ce{[H+]} = 2\times10^{-2}$$
Solving the quadratic, we deduce a value for $\ce{[H+]} = 2.21\times10^{-3}$. Why is this happening? And as per the followup question, how do we see the other parameters change if we increase the $\mathrm{p}$H by $1$? 


Owing to confusions about any use of buffer in the above parts, I shall add rest of the question of the author



$12.3)$  How would you adjust the final $\mathrm{p}$H of the solution saturated with $\ce{H2S}$ to reduce the concentration of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ from $\pu{0.010 mol dm^{–3}}$ to $\pu{1.0×10^–8 mol dm^{–3}}$? 
$12.4)$  You want to use acetic acid ($\ce{HAc}$) / sodium acetate ($\ce{NaAc}$) buffer to achieve concentration of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ $\pu{1.0×10^–8 mol dm^{–3}}$ as described above. Suppose that you are
making the buffer by mixing acetic acid and sodium acetate in water in a volumetric flask. Enough acetic acid was added to make the initial concentration $\pu{0.10 mol dm^{–3}}$. Considering that the precipitation reaction produces $\ce{H^+}$ $\ce{(Fe^2+ + H2S -> FeS(s) + 2H+)}$,
how would you adjust the initial concentration of sodium acetate to obtain concentration of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ equal to $\pu{1.0×10^–8 mol dm^{–3}}$ after equilibrium is established?
$12.5)$  What is the $\mathrm{p}$H of the buffer before $\ce{H2S}$ is introduced and $\ce{FeS}$ is precipitated?


Until you fix neglecting Cl- in charge balance, there is no point in further looking. That is the major mistake.  [S^2-] << [Cl-],  [OH-] << [Cl-], [HS-] < [Cl-]

Why have you omitted 2? And you should perhaps for now keep SH-. It is not an art. It is a math.

Your first equation, where the positive and the negative charges are compensated, is probably wrong. Study of the orders of magnitude is sufficient to get to this conclusion. Look why and how.
The positive side is [$\ce{H+}$] + $2 [\ce{Fe^{2+}}]$ and must be equal to the right-hand side, made of $4$ ions. The most important ion concentrations are [$\ce{Cl-}$] = $0.02$ M and [$\ce{HS-}$] which is a little less than [$\ce{H2S}$] = $0.18$ M. Whatever the exact value of [$\ce{HS-}$], the whole negative side sums up to a result greater than $0.02$ M (and smaller than $0.18 +0.02 = 0.20$ M).
As a consequence, the sum of the positive charges is greater than $0.02$ M (and maybe greater than $0.10$ M). As [$\ce{Fe^{2+}}$] is probably negligible with respect to $\ce{H+}$, it means that [$\ce{H+}$] must be at least $0.02$ M. This means that the pH must be lower than $2$. This happens when no buffers are present in solution. This is contrary to the initial hypothesis, where the pH is maintained around pH $7$ by buffers.
This also means that the first equation, comparing positive and negative charges, should be modified and should include the ions of the buffer.

why do you think the question involves the use of buffer? I still didn't quite get it

If no buffer is used in the mixture FeCl2 + H2S, its pH will go down to $1$ or $2$ in solution. In the beginning of this problem, the author states, just before question $2.1$ : In this problem, let’s consider the solubility equilibrium in a buffer solution.

please consider revisiting my question edit, sorry if you mind, I got pH as 1.6 there. i see there is confusion around the problem so i will add the full question for anyone wanting to read

I just copy your last calculations :  .... plugging this expression in the final charge-balance equation,
$\ce{\frac{[H^+]^2}{2.77×10^{−4}} + [H+] = 2×10^{−2}}$
Solving the quadratic, we deduce a value for [$\ce{H^+]=2.34×10^{−2}}$. This is impossible. It is impossible to add $0.0234$ to something positive and to get a final sum equal to $0.02$ (i.e. smaller than $0.0234$). Adding a+b cannot go to a result smaller than a, if a and b are both positive
